# Memory leak (?) while shared element transition

Tags: android, android-glide, android-transitions

I have RecycleView with StaggeredLayoutManager which shows images. these images are displayed via glide:

```
Glide.with(itemView.getContext()).load(post.image.url)
                .bitmapTransform(new RoundedCornersTransformation(itemView.getContext(), 10, 0, RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.TOP))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .into(image);
```

I have another activity, where is viewpager with details if these images. I want to make shared element transition between this image, and bigger image displayed in viewpager. However, when I do shared element transition, I can see that memory usage grows while I go to ViewPager's activity and back, and after some transitions OutOfMemory error is thrown. When I run activity without transition, memory is ok. What might cause such a leak?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?  I'm just about ready to abandon shared element transitions.